# Purely technical question about putting a link in a Q or an A

Tags: support

To illustrate my problem, see [Have attacks on humans by raptors other than owls been documented, excluding cases where they were defending their nests?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/have-attacks-on-humans-by-raptors-other-than-owls-been-documented-excluding-cas)

You will see that I have three references to three articles, and the links are very, very long.  It makes for an unattractive question.

Others just put in a single word link. How do I do that?  I have experimented, to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also put the reference and the link right in the sentence. This is what I do:

- Pick an important word or two to describe the link.
- Put those in brackets, like [this].
- Without adding a space, put your entire source link in parentheses, like (article web address). Make very sure not to add a space. I've done that a lot and it not only doesn't link, but it does weird-looking things!

What you end up with is an orange (or other color depending on the site) word to press on, which opens the page you referenced.

For example:

Ab2 asked this interesting question. [Have attacks on humans by raptors other than owls been documented, excluding cases where they were defending their nests?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/have-attacks-on-humans-by-raptors-other-than-owls-been-documented-excluding-cas)

becomes: Ab2 asked [this](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/have-attacks-on-humans-by-raptors-other-than-owls-been-documented-excluding-cas) interesting question.

Pressing on that orange word opens the source link, which is, in this case, your question.

I've taken the liberty of doing it to that question. I don't have edit privileges here, but if someone approves it, I hope it will look like what you're seeking. You can then see exactly what I did by checking your edit history. If there's anything you don't like, please just rollback the edit to your original version. I don't want to do anything unhelpful.

By the way, if you ever want a specific question edited, you can always leave a comment on it, and I'll gladly take care of it. I love editing! You can also try pinging me from chat, but I don't always get my messages!

Comment: Success!!......

Comment: @ab2 It looks awesome! :))

Answer (score 4):

On the desktop version the text box you type your post in has some icons above it, and one of these is the link button. I don't see it on the mobile version though.
[image]
You select the word you want made into a link and then click the link button. A box will open up allowing you to enter a URL.

Alternatively, you can do this manually. If you have a look at the source of a post that uses a link, you can see it looks like

```
[word][2]
```

and then at the bottom of the post you will have a section that looks like

```
[2]: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10241
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML A tags work in questions and answers.  For example:

<a href="the URL goes here">some words</a>

In this case, "some words" will be clickable with the actual URL hidden.